# Prove that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{\frac{(ik)^k}{(k!)^2}}=0$

Tags: limits

Prove that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{\frac{(ik)^k}{(k!)^2}}=0$$

I have been trying to get rid of the exponents by putting it in the exponent and then I need to prove that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}{(\ln{k}-\frac{2}{k}\ln{k!})}=\lim_{k\to\infty}{((1-\frac{2}{k})\ln{k}-\frac{2}{k}\ln{(k-1)!})}=-\infty$$

I dont know what my next step should be...

Answer (score 1):

Hint (without any consideration about the parity of $k$, but you will get it):

$\ln(k)-\frac{2}{k}\ln(k!) = \ln(k)-\frac{2}{k}( \sum_{i<\frac{k}{2}} \ln(i) + \sum_{i\geq \frac{k}{2}} \ln(i)  ) \leq \ln(k)- \ln(\frac{k}{2}) - \ln((\frac{k}{2})!) = \ln(2) - \ln((\frac{k}{2})!) $

Answer (score 0):

Recall a Sterling approximation inequality that you can look up in Wikipedia as I did. You have: $\ln k - 2\left(\dfrac{\ln1 + \ln2 +...+\ln k}{k}\right)=\left(\ln k - \dfrac{\ln 1 + \ln 2+...+ \ln k}{k}\right)-\dfrac{\ln 1 + \ln 2+...+ \ln k}{k}= \dfrac{\ln\left(\dfrac{k^k}{k!}\right)}{k}-\dfrac{\ln (k!)}{k}$. Apply Sterling inequality of the form: $\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot k^{k+\frac{1}{2}}\cdot e^{-k} < k!$ to the above equation's right hand side we have: $\dfrac{k^k}{k!} < \dfrac{e^k}{\sqrt{2k\pi}}\implies 0\leq \ln\left(\dfrac{k^k}{k!}\right)< k - \dfrac{\ln k}{2} - \dfrac{\ln (2\pi)}{2}\implies 0 \leq \dfrac{\ln \left(\dfrac{k^k}{k!}\right)}{k}< 1 - \dfrac{\ln k}{2k} - \dfrac{\ln (2\pi)}{2k}< 1\implies 0 \leq \displaystyle \lim_{k\to \infty} \dfrac{\ln \left(\dfrac{k^k}{k!}\right)}{k}\leq 1$. Also using Sterling inequality we have: $\sqrt[k]{k!} > \sqrt[k]{2\pi}\cdot k\cdot e^{-1}\cdot \sqrt[2k]{k}> \dfrac{k}{3}\implies \displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} \sqrt[k]{k!} = \infty\implies \displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} \ln\left(\sqrt[k]{k!}\right) = \infty\implies \displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} \dfrac{\ln (k!)}{k} = \infty\implies \displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} \left(\ln k - \dfrac{2}{k}\cdot \ln (k!)\right) = - \infty$.